# How do I draw two rectangles moving towards me in three.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, three.js

I am using [three.js](/questions/tagged/three.js) to draw a couple of 3D objects.

Currently, I have drawn one rectangle that is moving towards me from the left:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
   canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
  <title> </title>
 <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
  <script>
            function five(x){
                x_rounded = 5 * Math.round(x/5);
                return(x_rounded);
            }
            var transparency = {0: "00", 5: "0D", 10: "1A", 15: "26", 20: "33", 25: "40", 30: "4D", 35: "59", 40: "66", 45: "73", 50: "80", 55: "8C", 60: "99", 65: "A6", 70: "B3", 75: "BF", 80: "CC", 85: "D9", 90: "E6", 95: "F2", 100: "FF"};
   var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

   var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
            mouse.x = 0;
            mouse.y = 0;
            var speed = 0.1;
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

   var shapes = [];
            camera.position.x = 4;
            shapes.push(new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 3, 0.75 ));
            camera.position.x = 6;
            shapes.push(new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 3, 0.75 ));
      camera.position.z = 25;
            trans = transparency[five(camera.position.z)];
   var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: '#'+trans+'#F5F5F5' } );
   var cubes = [];
            for(var i = 0;i<shapes.length;i++){
                cube = new THREE.Mesh( shapes[i], material )
                cubes.push(cube);
      }
            
            scene.add(cubes[0]);
            scene.add(cubes[1]);

                camera.position.x = 4;
   var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );

                camera.position.z -= speed;
                trans = transparency[five(camera.position.z)];
                col = '#'+trans+'#F5F5F5';
                material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:  col} );
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(shapes[0], material));
                if(camera.position.z <= 0){
                    camera.position.z = 25;
                    // shapes.push(new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 3, 0.75 ));
                    // cubes.push(new THREE.Mesh(shapes[shapes.length-1], material));
                    // scene.add(cubes[cubes.length-1]);
                }
    // cube.rotation.x += 0.05;
    // cube.rotation.y += 0.05;
    //             cube.rotation.z += 0.05;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
   };

   render();

function onMouseMove( event ) {

    // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
 // (-1 to +1) for both components

 mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1
 mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1
}



window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );

window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
  </script>
 </body>
```

However, I now want to draw another rectangle that is moving towards me from the right (mirror image of the one on the left). I tried adding a new rectangle and changing `camera.position.y` and `.x`, but nothing worked. Also, every time the rectangle loops over, I want it to fade on from the background to the foreground. Is this possible in [three.js](/questions/tagged/three.js)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometries = [];
geometries.push(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 3, 0.75));
geometries.push(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 3, 0.75));

var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000
});
var meshes = [];
meshes.push(new THREE.Mesh(geometries[0], material));
meshes.push(new THREE.Mesh(geometries[1], material));

meshes[0].position.set(2, 0, -10);
scene.add(meshes[0]);

meshes[1].position.set(-2, 0, -15);
scene.add(meshes[1]);

var time = new Date();
function render() {
  // delta in ms
  var newTime = new Date();
  var delta = newTime - time;
  time = newTime;

  // move the boxes
  var mult = 0.005;
  meshes[1].position.z += delta * mult;
  meshes[0].position.z += delta * mult;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.js"></script>
```

I'd strongly suggest that you read the docs first since your code wasn't good at all, there are some small facts that you need to know first:

1. To render things you need a renderer, a camera and some objects to render
2. The objects to render must be stored in a [scene graph](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scene_graph), `THREE.Scene` will hold all the objects to render
3. with `renderer.render(scene, camera)` THREE will map all the 3d objects in our
   scene to a 2d plane (which is what we see a.k.a the screen), after the representation is computed is rendered with `THREE.WebGLRenderer`

In the example above instead of moving the camera I moved the objects (which I assumed that's what you wanted), first thing to note is that THREE uses the right hand rule, by default any object created (as well as the `camera`) is positioned in the origin, the camera is a special object because it also has a vector which points to the direction the camera is looking (it's looking to the `-z` initially)

For this simple example we don't need to move the camera, how about moving the objects away from the camera? we can do that by setting the `z` coordinate of the objects to be moved away from the camera (which would by any multiple of the unit `-z` vector), also since you want to have an object to the right and to the left how about changing it's `x` coordinates, the object on the left needs to have an `x` coordinate multiple of the unit `-x` vector and the object on the right a multiple of the unit `x` vector. Finally in the game loop we just need to move them towards the camera i.e. changing it's `z` coordinate.

Please make sure to read a little bit about 3d math, [Udacity's course](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs291) is a good place to start :)

Comment: see the source code of this demo http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials, most of the realistic materials need actually a light source